# create vertical table from an array with key and value

Tags: php, arrays

So, for example i have the following array:

```
array(
    'q1'=>array(1, 2, 5, 6, 2),
    'q2'=>array(1, 2, 5, 6, 2)
);
```

from that array, I want to create a vertical html table that looks like:

```
+----+----+
| q1 | q2 |
+----+----+
| 1  | 1  |
| 2  | 2  |
| .. | .. |
| 2  | 2  |
+----+----+
```

how to achieve this goal? I stuck on simple `foreach()`

```
$html = '<table>';
foreach($data as $header=>$cell){
    $html .= '<td>'.$header.'</td>';
    foreach($cell as $row){
        $html .= '<tr><td>'.$row->value.'</td></tr>';
    }
}
$html .= '</table>';
```

Comment: Can you print_r($data)?

Comment: @aldrin27 : it's a standard object coming from Yii Query.

Comment: Build the headers then iterate through the rows.

Answer (score 0):

if $data is your array with q1 and q2 then

```
$html = '<table>';

$html .= '<tr><td>q1</td><td>q2</td></tr>';

foreach($data['q1'] as $index => $record){
    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$record.'</td>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$data['q2'][$index].'</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';
}
$html .= '</table>';
```

Comment: the q1 and q2 is just an example, actually the header can be vary, more then 2 headers with different names.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. here is the solution

```
$html = '<table>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        foreach($data as $key=>$cell){
            $html .= '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
        }
        $html .= '</tr>';

        $first = reset($data);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($first); $i++){
            $html .= '<tr>';
            foreach($data as $d){
                $html .= '<td>'.$d[$i]->value.'</td>';
            }
            $html .= '</tr>';
        }
        $html .= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code.Hope it works for you.

```
<?php
$data =array(
    'q1'=>array(1, 2, 5, 6, 2),
    'q2'=>array(1, 2, 5, 6, 2),
    'q3'=>array(1, 2, 5, 6, 2),
    'q4'=>array(1, 2, 5, 6, 2)
);
$html = '<table>';
 $html.='<tr>';
 $main_keys =array_keys($data);
 foreach($data  as $key=>$v)
 {
    $html.='<tr>';
    foreach($main_keys as $k)
    {
     $html.='<td>'.$k.'</td>';
    }
    $html.='</tr>';
    for($i=0;$i<count($v);$i++)
    {
         $html.='<tr>';
        foreach($main_keys as $k)
        {
         $html.='<td>'.$data[$k][$i].'</td>';
        }
        $html.='</tr>';
    }
    break;
 }

$html .= '</table>';
?>
```